# Spring Bean Creation: Requested bean is currently in creation

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, javabeans, autowired

I have a problem trying to autowire a bean that is defined in the same class.

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
public ClassName ..

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myCustomBean")
    private MyCustomClass myBean;

    @Bean("myCustomBean")
    public MyCustomClass getMyCustomBean() {
        MyCustomClass c = new MyCustomClass();
        return c;
    }

    @Bean("otherBeanThatIwant")
    public OtherClassOfMyProject() {
        OtherClass oc = new ...
        oc.setMyCustomClass(this.c);
        return oc;
    }
```

This code gives me an error such as: **BeanCreationException**: Error creating bean with name "otherBeanThatIwant"

...
...
...

Could not autowire field myBean ... .... **BeanCurrentlyInCreationException**.

I google it, but i couldn't find any answer to my problem.

Any clue?

Thanks in advice!
Greetings

Comment: Your configuration class is creating the instance of the bean while it is also expecting it to be autowired. That isn't gocint to work. You can just reference the `@Bean` method if you need it as a reference in your other bean or just `@Autowire` it in your bean not in the configuration class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
The problema is that i have another project that works with this kind of configuration... :(
I dont know if there is another specific configuration that i am missing...

Comment: I doubt that. That other project has probably the bean in a different configuration file then the one that is requiring it.

Comment: I had some issue with my web.xml configuration.
I added the contextClass and contextConfigLocation and now it is working! Thanks for your time!